# What is the pandas idiom to convert a time column into datetime format?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm trying to convert time in a column to datetime:

```
(2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0)

df_date = pd.DataFrame({'date': [(2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0), 
                                 (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0),
                                 (2015, 12, 28, 23, 50, 40, 0, 362, 0)]})
df_date.date = df_date.date.apply(lambda x:x[:6])
# df_date['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_date['date'], format =%Y,%M,%D,%H,%M,%S) #(doesn't work)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are the extra fields?  `datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])`  The last two values in your tuples do not correspond to fields in the datetime constructor.

Comment: (tm_year=2000, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0,
                 tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=335, tm_isdst=-1)  https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime.datetime`to convert the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df_date = pd.DataFrame({'date': [(2015, 12, 29, 0, 30, 50, 1, 363, 0), 
                                 (2015, 12, 28, 23, 59, 12, 0, 362, 0),
                                 (2015, 12, 28, 23, 50, 40, 0, 362, 0)]})
df_date.date = df_date.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(*x[:6]))

>>> df_date.date
                 date
0 2015-12-29 00:30:50
1 2015-12-28 23:59:12
2 2015-12-28 23:50:40
```